# Implementing CWindowImpl::OnFinalMessage properly for both stack and heap-allocated window objects

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, atl

ATL's `CWindowImpl` has a handy overridable method `OnFinalMessage`, which is called when the underlying window is destroyed.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cwindowimpl-class?view=msvc-160#onfinalmessage) specifically condones deleting your class object within this method:

> The default implementation of `OnFinalMessage` does nothing, but you can
> override this function to handle cleanup before destroying a window.
> If you want to automatically delete your object upon the window
> destruction, you can call **delete this;** in this function.

My question is: what if you'd like your `CWindowImpl` class to be usable either on the stack or the heap?  From what I understand, it's not safe to call `delete` on a stack object, and there's also no reliable way for an object to determine where it's been allocated. Is there some strategy you can use to only call `delete this` conditionally?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: it is very easy detect, are object (or any pointer) located in current thread stack - https://pastebin.com/BkK6CsWN

Comment: @RbMm What if the `CWindowImpl` is a member of another class, and the parent class was allocated on the heap?

Comment: If object allocated in heap, it cannot containing member in stack.

Comment: Anyway, if you assume that object can be not allocated separate, but part of another object, you can not delete it

Comment: You'll know.  Creating a window on the stack is generally only sensible for a dialog.  In which case you'd derive from CDialogImpl.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I had (but which I haven't tested yet) is this:

In the standard `CWindowImpl` class, don't call `delete`. Use this version on the stack.

But then maybe set up a mix-in class like this, which can be used on the fly when allocating on the heap:

```
template <class T>
class CSelfCleaningWindow : public T
{
public:
    void OnFinalMessage(HWND hwnd)
    {
        __super::OnFinalMessage(hwnd);
        delete this;
    }
};
```

But I gotta test this to see if it actually works.